# ¿Cómo guarda una imagenes dentro de la carpeta de proyecto c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, imagen

Esta vez consulto este sitio porque necesito una ayuda para **especificar una ruta para guardar una imágen dentro de una carpeta del proyecto en C#.** para que en cualquier computadora se pueda leer la imagen.

La necesito guardar porque después la debo buscar y ponerla en un archivo html.

Debo resaltar que la imagen es un grafo generado con código graphviz. La imagen la creo de esta forma:

```
//Metodo que uso para enviarle la ruta que supuestamente tengo en mi proyecto         
generarImagen("grafo.dot", @"~/Imagenes/");            

 private void generarImagen(string nombre, string ruta )
        {
            try
            {
                var command = string.Format("dot -Tpng {0} -o {1}", Path.Combine(ruta, nombre), Path.Combine(ruta, nombre.Replace(".dot", ".png")));

                var procStarInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/C " + command);

                var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

                proc.StartInfo = procStarInfo;

                proc.Start();

                proc.WaitForExit();

                MessageBox.Show("Imagen creada", "Información");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

Este método que genera la imagen no me lanza a la Exception, y me muestra el mensaje que la imagen se creó, pero dentro de la carpeta Imagenes que tengo destinada para el grafo no se crea la imagen.

El método también funciona porque si le escribo que lo coloque en Documentos si genera la imagen, pero en este caso no. Agradecería cualquier ayuda al respecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has comprobado los permisos de escritura de la aplicación en la carpeta Imagenes?

Comment: No creo que sean permisos, las carpetas tipo documentos, imágenes, etc no requieren permisos pues son carpetas de usuario, el proyecto supongo que está en la carpeta projects de la carpeta visual studio 201x que está dentro de mis documentos. Yo mas bien creo que se debe a como le pasa la ruta.

Comment: Coloca un breakpoint en la línea "var procStarInfo = new System...." y mira el valor que tiene la variable command.

Comment: O pues he resuelto algo del problema, hice el breakpoint y me percaté que el var command estaba mal la ruta donde buscaba el archivo .dot.    Aún así todavía no obtengo el resultado que espero, porque ahora la ruta donde me guarda es el /bin/Debug/Imagenes//. Pero esta ruta la comienza desde el disco local C://...bin/Debug/Imagenes/.                             Obviamente esto ya me guarda pero la idea es que se pueda guardar dentro del proyecto sin la direcciónes desde el disco C://    . Me doy a entender.